# Showing a div on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm simply trying to `toggle()` `<div class="reveal">` when the button is pushed.

I'll have multiple buttons and corresponding `<div>`'s on the page, so I just want to `toggle()` the next instance on the page using `$(this).next("div.reveal").toggle();`

Nothing happens and there are no errors. What did I do wrong?

HTML:

```
<article class="customerQuotes">
    <blockquote>Blah
        <cite><b>Name</b> - Company</cite>
    </blockquote>
    <button class="button right">More</button>

</article>

<div class="reveal">
    <div class="right">
        //stuff here
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).next("div.reveal").toggle();
});
```

CSS:

```
 .reveal{
    display: none;
    float: left;
    clear: both;
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to call `.next` on the parent element, since `.reveal` is its sibling.

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("div.reveal").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Thats because `$(this).next("div.reveal")` is `undefined`. There is no `div.reveal` next to a button element.

You would need to restructure your html like this:

```
<article class="customerQuotes">
    <blockquote>Blah
        <cite><b>Name</b> - Company</cite>
    </blockquote>
    <button class="button right">More</button>

    <!-- Note here that div.reveal is sibling to a button so 
         .next() will find this element -->
    <div class="reveal">
       <div class="right">
        //stuff here
       </div>
    </div>
</article>
```

**or** change your selector for JQuery to grab next reveal from the parent element like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $(this).parent().next("div.reveal").toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Like others said you forgot to use the next() method on the parent().

However, any time you change the structure of your HTML this code will break! Better reference the elements to be revealed explicitly. One simple way is to save the target as data on the button:

```
<button data-target="#reveal1" class="button right">More</button>
...
<div id="reveal1"></div>
```

Your JS would then look like this:

```
$(".button").click(function() {
    $( $(this).data("target") ).toggle();
});
```

This will work regardless of where you place your button and div.